# MS Access: Using a Date Between a Start Date and End Date for a Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Question: Create a query that shows a listing of all kennels that were occupied on February 14, 2015.

So what I have is the Kennel ID, Start Date (of being in a kennel) and End Date (of being in the kennel)

I'm not sure how I am supposed to extract the date February 14, 2015 from being in between Start Date and End Date.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways of querying this depending on your end goal.

Have a read here for a good visual representation of how to get the results http://www.baldyweb.com/OverLap.htm

In a simple query hard coded to one date this would equate to Criteria like

[End Date] >= #02/14/2017# AND [Start Date] <= #02/14/2017#

Comment: So would it be something like StartDate <= 2015/02/04EndDate And EndDate >= 2015/02/04StartDate ? This is supposed to be a query as well.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks Minty! The dates are year first for me though :p